# How to prevent from scrolling UITableView up when NSFetchedResultsController add new record?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My `UITableView` is scrolling up once I add a new comment to CoreData. NSFetchedResultsController knows about it, puts this comment at the bottom of the table, and scroll table to top. Is it normal?

My example:

Just before I add a comment:

[image]

Just after I add a comment (not expected behavior):

[image]

It should be just like this (*after I swipe it by hand manually*):

[image]

This may be connected with following situation:

1. This is sort descriptor of my `NSFetchedResultsController`:

   ```
   NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false) //from the latest to the oldest
   ```
2. But I need to display my comments for reversed index paths (*the latest are at the very bottom*). In other words, everywhere when I need to use `indexPath` I use:

   ```
   private func reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {
       return NSIndexPath(forRow: fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count - indexPath.row - 1, inSection: 0)
   }
   ```

`NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`:

```
//MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(newIndexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    case .Move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(indexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([reversedIndexPathForIndexPath(newIndexPath)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Is it connected to my problem?

Comment: just disable tableview's scrolling before adding new record

Comment: @PiyushPatel  `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false`, still moves to top

Comment: Use : tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO.

Comment: Do you calling `reloadData` on table view in FRC delegate's `controllerDidChangeContent:` method?

Comment: @bteapot, no, should I?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Show us implementation of FRC delegate methods.

Comment: @bteapot updated a question

Comment: Well, i'll write an answer.

Comment: @bteapot ok, waiting for solution:) thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edited answer:**

I was able to reproduce this glitch with the following steps:

1. `UITableView` with its `rowHeight` set to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and non-zero `estimatedRowHeight`.
2. Table scrolled to its very bottom, with the last cell fully visible at the bottom margin.
3. Inserting the new cell below the last one results in visual shift of the cells a few points down (in my setup it differs from 5 to 40).

The source of this behavior needs additional investigation.

For now the only solution is not to use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and return row heights from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

By the way, implementation of inverted index paths has one significant flaw. When FRC calls it's delegate method `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`, all deletion index paths belongs to pre-change data set, and all insertion index paths - to post-change one. When you are in-beetween `controllerWillChangeContent:` and `controllerDidChangeContent:`, `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` will contain post-change data set, i suppose (needs to be checked, though).

Comment: No, it cannot be like that. This way will work only if I want to display ALL messages. What if I need to display only 10 latest messages?

Comment: Then do descending. Now about jumping to top: do you using estimated heights of rows?

Comment: yes, my tableView use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: Here may be the problem. Can you try to switch this off and return some constant like `100` from 
`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: No, because the height of my cells are different and depends on length of text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92960/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-bteapot).

Answer (score 3):

I found something that worked for me. 
I encountered the same problem, and my estimatedRowHeight was 33 and all of my cells are greater than 33.

I just changed my estimatedRowHeight to my maximum cell height(or greater than your maximum cell height)

```
    self.table.estimatedRowHeight = 310
    self.table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

worked like a charm, all cells are now autoresizing and uitableview is not scrolling to top or bottom when core data performs an update/delete/insert